# Can't find the reason my app returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, jsx

I'm using useState to store the data returned from an api:

```
function App() {
  const [{ ipAddressData, shouldLoadItems }, setModel] = useState<AppState>({
    ipAddressData: [],
    shouldLoadItems: true,
  });
  const [ipAddress, setIpAddress] = useState("");
  const ipDataUrl = `https://geo.ipify.org/${ipAddress}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(ipDataUrl);
      const data: IpAddress[] = await response.json();
      setModel({
        ipAddressData: data,
        shouldLoadItems: false,
      });
    };
    if (shouldLoadItems) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [shouldLoadItems]);


  function inputIp(e: { preventDefault: () => void }) {
    setModel((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        shouldLoadItems: true,
      };
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Then i'm trying to return the data but i get the following error: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2B5T.png)

```
  const { ip, location, domains, as, isp }: IpAddressData = ipAddressData;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className={mainCss}>
        <h1 className={mainTitleCss}>IP Address Tracker</h1>
        <form className={searchBarContainerCss} onSubmit={inputIp}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search for any IP address or domain"
            className={searchInputCss}
            onChange={(e) => setIpAddress(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="" className={searchBarButtonCss} />
        </form>
        <Results
          ip={ip}
          location={getLocation(
            location.city,
            location.country,
            location.postalCode
          )}
          timezone={location.timezone}
          isp={isp}
        />

function getLocation(city: string, country: string, postalCode: string) {
  return `${city}, ${country} ${postalCode}`;
}
```

Results.tsx:

```
interface IpAddressProps {
  ip: string;
  location: string;
  timezone: string;
  isp: string;
}

const Results: FC<IpAddressProps> = ({ ip, location, timezone, isp }) => {
  return (
    <div className={resultsContainerCss}>
      <div className={resultCss}>
        <div className={resultTitleCss}>IP Address</div>
        <div className={resultInfoCss}>{ip}</div>
      </div>
      <div className={resultCss}>
        <div className={resultTitleCss}>Location</div>
        <div className={resultInfoCss}>{location}</div>
      </div>
      <div className={resultCss}>
        <div className={resultTitleCss}>Timezone</div>
        <div className={resultInfoCss}>UTC {timezone}</div>
      </div>
      <div className={resultCss}>
        <div className={resultTitleCss}>ISP</div>
        <div className={resultInfoCss}>{isp}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Results;
```

index.ts where my interfaces are stored:

```
interface Location {
  country: string;
  region: string;
  city: string;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  postalCode: string;
  timezone: string;
  geonameId: number;
}
interface As {
  asn: number;
  name: string;
  route: string;
  domain: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface IpAddressData {
  ip: string;
  location: Location;
  domains: string[];
  as: As;
  isp: string;
}

export interface IpAddress {
  data: IpAddressData;
}
```

When i console.log ipAddressData it returns the data from the api as expected so i don't know what the problem is

Comment: I think, you are exposing your `api key` up there. Check ipDataUrl variabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, `AppState` interface had `ipAddressData` defined as an array when in reality it should be an object and that was the reason it was returning undefined.

```
interface AppState {
  ipAddressData: IpAddressData[];
  shouldLoadItems: boolean;
}
```

Should be this instead:

```
interface AppState {
  ipAddress: IpAddress | undefined;
  shouldLoadItems: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these two blocks of codes are in conflict with each other.

```
const [{ ipAddressData, shouldLoadItems }, setModel] = useState<AppState>({
    ipAddressData: [],
    shouldLoadItems: true,
});
```

```
setModel({
    ipAddressData: data,
    shouldLoadItems: false,
});
```

There is a variable called `ipAddressData` in your `useState` array and there is one inside `setModel` as well. If you hover over the `ipAddressData` inside your `setModel` call. It'd say `ipAddressData` is not assignable.

I'd suggest to change the first variable name returned by your `useState` to something like below:

```
  const [data, setModel] = useState<AppState>({
    ipAddressData: [],
    shouldLoadItems: true,
  });
```

so that when you call:

```
setModel({
    ipAddressData: data,
    shouldLoadItems: false,
});
```

it's not saying `ipAddressData` is not assignable.

Later, if you want to refer to the `ipAddressData` or `shouldLoadItems` value. You can call it like `data.ipAddressData` or `data.shouldLoadItems`.

after that, see if your error `Uncaught TypeError` disappears or not.